# AddSlahes Javascript / PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have an HTML page with a form. When a user fills the input field, I search the database for a match. A list is displayed with possible matches and can be clicked, the possible match will then be copied to the input field. All works well for "normal" text, but when a record contains an ' the possible match is not copied to the input field. Although in the PHP script I did an "addslashes", but it seems that I can't pass the value to the Javascript.

The PHP code is this:

```
$SafedbCheck = addslashes($dbCheck_result[1]);
<li class='CheckListItem' onClick='n0400AddResults_Click(<?php echo( $jsCheck)?>,"<?php echo( $SafedbCheck)?>")'><a href="#"><?php echo($dbCheck_result[1])?></a></li>
```

Which results in the following HTML lines:

```
<li class='CheckListItem' onClick='n0400AddResults_Click(1,"Gabe\'s Brand New Brand")'><a href="#">Gabe's Brand New Brand</a></li>
```

and

```
<li class='CheckListItem' onClick='n0400AddResults_Click(1,"Gabrie")'><a href="#">Gabrie</a></li>
```

For testing the Javascript function:

```
function n0400AddResults_Click( jsCheck, SearchItem )
{    alert( SearchItem ); }
```

Which works fine for the second line, but not for the first line even though the var I'm passing to the Javascript is slashed. Do I need to do some extra slashthingy?

Comment: If you use `addslashes` you are ALWAYS doing it wrong... When passing a value to JavaScript use `json_encode()`. Since you are using it inside a HTML attribute, you need to use `htmlspecialchars()`, too (after JSON-encoding it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three layers of code here.

1. Some data
2. Some JavaScript
3. Some HTML

Let's start with the data:

```
$jsCheck
```

You need to escape the data in a fashion suitable for inserting in the JavaScript.

In PHP, this is best done using the `json_encode` function which, despite the name, will convert any basic data structure into a JavaScript literal (not just objects and arrays).

Note that this will also add the appropriate quote characters so you should not include them yourself.

```
json_encode($jsCheck);
```

You then need to escape the data in a fashion suitable for inserting into the HTML.

In PHP, this is best done using the `htmlspecialchars` function.

```
htmlspecialchars(json_encode($jsCheck));
```

Putting this with the rest of your code gives you:

```
<li class="CheckListItem" onClick="n0400AddResults_Click(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($jsCheck)); ?>,<?php htmlspecialchars(json_encode($SafedbCheck)?;>)">
```

---

That said, the approach has a couple of issues.

- List items are not interactive items. The user will only be able to activate them using a mouse or other pointing device … and you have an anchor already (which is an interactive element).
- `onclick` attributes are not [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

You'd probably be better off with something that stores the data in the URL you pass to the `href` attribute or, failing that, in `data-*` attributes and then binding a JavaScript event handler with `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks your first solution worked. I did read your extra info about this not being the most ideal way to work, but I wouldn't know where to start. Maybe when I'm somewhat more advanced :-)